# ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError (cannot touch on a new record object) rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I recently upgraded a rails 3 application to rails 4. When I am trying to create a new Test, below code from before_save fails to execute. The same code works fine with rails 3.

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :assignments, :dependent => :destroy

  before_save do
    if code_changed? 
      self.assignments.each{|a| a.touch}
    end
  end
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :test, :touch => true
end
```

I see the below error when I create a new test.

```
ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError (cannot touch on a new record object):
app/models/test.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Test>'
app/models/test.rb:6:in `block in <class:Test>'
app/controllers/tests_controller.rb:423:in `create'
```

Any suggestions to resolve this issue ??

Answer (score 3):

The error is raised because there is a new assignment object and not saved in the database. The touch can not be called on new record.

Just check for new_record? before calling touch.

```
before_save do
 if code_changed? 
     self.assignments.each{|a| a.touch unless a.new_record?}
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried this approach and it doesn't give me any error but I am wondering why this code doesn't give any error in rails3.

Comment: I checked from rails3 console rails4 console and it behaves differently in both places.                                                                                               
rails 3: t = Test.new
t.touch  ## returns false.
rails4: t = Test.new 
t.touch  ## returns ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError: cannot touch on a new record object

Answer (score 0):

It is because your function that is before save needs to be private. And you can restructure it like this for readability.

```
class Test < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :assignments, :dependent => :destroy
  before_save :before_save_function
        
  private

  def before_save_function
    if code_changed? 
      self.assignments.each{|a| a.touch}
    end
  end
end
```

Cheers! Hope it Helps.

Comment: I don't think that's it. ActiveRecord callbacks don't care if the method is private or not, and it certainly wouldn't raise the error message that's being raised